# Force Liferay to invoke LDAP Import of Users/Groups

Tags: ldap, liferay-6

How do start the LDAP import process from Portal Administration UI in Liferay?

1. Is there any Liferay Utility or script that can be re-used?
2. Can we reset the LDAP import timer from the Liferay Administration UI or Script Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Javascript LDAP Force Import : In Control Panel > Server Administration > Scripts > Javascript

   `Packages.com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterUtil.importFromLDAP();`

   This will work on if LDAP import is enabled.
2. I don't think there is any direct way to reset the LDAP import timer apart from the following property in Liferay portal-ext.properties.

   `ldap.import.interval=10`

Ref: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/9515697

Answer (score 2):

It is little late to reply to this mail but if anyone is looking for a quick solution on importing ldap user in liferay then this post would help.

Refer to the below link. Its an application for importing ldap users and it is available for free on liferay marketplace.

https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/52427499